# CSS, Button disappearing when resizing window

Tags: html, css

In my project, I have a button in the body of my div. When I resize the window, the button mysteriously disappears. I have searched for other solutions, however none have worked for me.

Here is my code:

```css
.section-1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  background: url("https://udodjfjfjfoeoeo.com.dekffrfr") no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.main-signup-btn {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 60px;
  width: 245px;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
  font-weight: bolder;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bolder;
  top: 253px;
  left: -680px;
}
```

```html
<div class="section-1">
  <div class="overlay-1"></div>
  <button class="main-signup-btn">Sign up now, uue</button>
</div>
```

Anybody know the issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your css  `.main-signup-btn` you absolutely positioned the button to -680px which sends the button offscreen. remove the - and use only 680px and your button will appear somewhere near the center or a little to the right depending on your screen width. you can completely remove the `left: -680px;` completely and see i positioned normal at the beginning of the div / screen. You can try this

```
.main-signup-btn {
background-color: transparent;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid white;
height: 60px;
width: 245px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
font-weight: bolder;
border-radius: 3px;
color: white;
font-weight: bolder;
top: 253px;
/* left: -680px; */ /* This line is sending the button offscreen to the left, change the value or remove completely  */
```

}

Comment: Hello. I have deleted the left property, and inserted `right: 680px`, however the same issue occurs. I need the button to be in this exact position

Comment: Any suggestions?